# Copy cell from one sheet to another, repeat for all cells within range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to repeat the code below for cells in the range A2 to A46 that contain values.

```
Worksheets("Full Qual").Range("A2").Copy _
  Destination:=Worksheets("Test").Range("D4")
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=2, To:=4, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

The goal is to copy the cell from worksheet "Full Qual" to worksheet "Test", print it, then move on to the next cell below and repeat for all cells with values up to cell A46.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Dim N As Long, v As Range
For N = 2 To 46
    Set v = Worksheets("Full Qual").Range("A" & N)
    If v.Value <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Full Qual").Range("A" & N).Copy _
          Destination:=Worksheets("Test").Range("D4")
        ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=2, to:=4, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    End If
Next N
```

**UNTESTED**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I used it but changed for N = 2 to 8 to avoid wasting too much paper and ink. There are only 3 values within this range and it ended up printing all 3 copies with the value of A5 (the second cell within the range that has a value). i had a similar problem when I manually repeated my original code.